Block size output from lsblk and blockdev don't match

Why the output of LOG-SEC column and --getbsz in the following don't match? Are these values of different quantities? How to find actual values? And is the output of following stat command always equal to  blockdev --getbsz?

$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,PHY-SeC,LOG-SEC,FSTYPE
NAME                     PHY-SEC LOG-SEC FSTYPE
zram0                       4096    4096 
nvme0n1                      512     512 
├─nvme0n1p1                  512     512 ext4
├─nvme0n1p2                  512     512 ext4
├─nvme0n1p3                  512     512 ext4
├─nvme0n1p4                  512     512 vfat
└─nvme0n1p5                  512     512 LVM2_member
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraRoot      512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraSwap      512     512 swap
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuSwap      512     512 swap
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot      512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuHome      512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraHome      512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-Data            512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-Documents       512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-Media           512     512 ext4
  ├─vgubuntu-Backup          512     512 ext4
  └─vgubuntu-SecureCrypt     512     512 crypto_LUKS
    └─Secure                 512     512 ext4
$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/vgubuntu/Data 
4096
$ sudo blockdev --getpbsz /dev/vgubuntu/Data 
512

Also,
$ stat -fc %s .
4096

From man page

--getbsz: Print the blocksize in bytes. This size does not describe device topology. It's the size used internally by the kernel and it may be modified (for example) by filesystem driver on mount.
--getpbsz: Get physical block (sector) size.


Those values are remapped at many different levels of the device -> kernel -> os -> application stack, as suggested by the man page excerpt you posted, which results in different values being shown (I don't know enough details on the process to provide a good answer to this, but that's the gist), moreover beware of any value pertaining to physical sector sizes in regards to SSDs as obviously those lack sectors in the first place, so any value shown would be just a (possibly optimized) dummy value.

About GNU stat -f see also What can f_bsize be used for? (Is it similar to st_blksize?)
